# Seṭing up MySQL separately than where Web Server is running on

Tags: mysql, webserver

is it ideal to have MySQL running on different machine than on the server machine that runs Apache or php . I was think of a scenario if two different web server installed physically on different machine accessing database than it can be useful that if one web server goes down other server would still be running if MySQL is deployed on a separate machine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course. 
Same resources shared between apache/php and MySQL are not a good option.

Divide and conquer my brother!

Comment: What are the right approaches used at production level for such an implementation ? Are there tools to deploy and manage such setups ?

Comment: Yes. You could for example set up a Server in Amazon EC2 Instance with Apache/PHP and a MySQL Database in amazon with RDS.